# Copy the results into another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet where I do some calculus, and I want to copy the full “results” to another sheet, called “Results”.
The thing is I have values in columns A and B, C and D, E and F (in pairs, they are connected). I want to copy them (in pairs) and paste them in the sheet “Results”, for example in Columns D and E, but all “in line”.
Like first, A and B, then two rows above, start the values from C and D, and then (two rows above) i paste values from E and F.

Therefore, is there any way where I can adjust the print area, depending on the size of my results?

I have this:

[image: i have this]

I want this

[image: i want this]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or two to clarify what you're asking for?

Comment: @AleksandarMisich i added two screenshots. let me know if i was not clear enough. those "pairs" are my results.

Comment: Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Without showing your own coding efforts to get what you need, you'll get little help. Also, the text of what you wrote and your screenshots do not really match. The text of what you wrote seems more complex, logically, then the screenshot example.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work, although your explanation and your figures don't match:

```
Sub test()

'Select sheet where data source is placed
    Sheets("Data Source").Activate

'Declare variables for ranges
    Dim Rng1, Rng2, Rng3 As Range
        Set Rng1 = Range(Range("A3"), Range("B3").End(xlDown)) 'Define range in columns A:B
        Set Rng2 = Range(Range("C3"), Range("D3").End(xlDown)) 'Define range in columns C:D
        Set Rng3 = Range(Range("E3"), Range("F3").End(xlDown)) 'Define range in columns E:F

'Declare variables quantity of rows in each range
    Dim r, r1, r2, r3 As Long
        r = 2   'first blank rows
        r1 = Rng1.Rows.Count
        r2 = Rng2.Rows.Count
        r3 = Rng3.Rows.Count

'Go to sheet Results
    Sheets("Results").Activate

'Copy data into sheet Results
    Range(Cells(r + 1, 1), Cells(r, 2).Offset(r1, 0)).Value = Rng1.Value
    r = r + r1 + 2  '(2) represents the number of rows spacing the two tables
    Range(Cells(r + 1, 1), Cells(r, 2).Offset(r2, 0)).Value = Rng2.Value
    r = r + r2 + 2  '(2) represents the number of rows spacing the two tables
    Range(Cells(r + 1, 1), Cells(r, 2).Offset(r3, 0)).Value = Rng3.Value

End Sub
```